# Vulkan VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation is Wrong Bit-Type

Tags: c, windows, mingw, vulkan, validation-layers

## The Problem:

Hello!  I am developing a Vulkan project between two 64-bit Windows systems, using the same MinGW/GCC build system on both.  I am writing the program in C to challenge myself, and it has gone well until now.  When I run my program on System 1, validation layers work as expected.  **Please note: the program works just fine on both systems with validation layers disabled.**  On System 2, this is my console output when I run my program:

```
INFO: 3 Vulkan extension(s) required by GLFW:
        VK_KHR_surface
        VK_KHR_win32_surface
        VK_EXT_debug_utils
        All GLFW-required Vulkan extensions are supported!
INFO: 1 Vulkan validation layer(s) required:
        VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation
        Required Vulkan validation layers are supported!
ERROR: loader_get_json: Failed to open JSON file E:\Epic Games\Launcher\Portal\Extras\Overlay\EOSOverlayVkLayer-Win32.json
ERROR: loader_get_json: Failed to open JSON file E:\Epic Games\Launcher\Portal\Extras\Overlay\EOSOverlayVkLayer-Win64.json
WARNING: Layer VK_LAYER_OBS_HOOK uses API version 1.2 which is older than the application specified API version of 1.3. May cause issues.
WARNING: Layer VK_LAYER_OBS_HOOK uses API version 1.2 which is older than the application specified API version of 1.3. May cause issues.
ERROR: Requested layer "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation" was wrong bit-type!
ERROR: Vulkan instance creation failed with result code -6!
ERROR: Vulkan debug messenger creation failed with result code -7!
Assertion failed: instance != VK_NULL_HANDLE, file C:\Users\Kade\Documents\westy\src\lib\glfw-3.3.2\src\vulkan.c, line 305
```

I have come to the conclusion that the first two `loader_get_json` errors are not the source of the problem (see [this GitHub ticket](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/56089)).

I am not using the `VK_LAYER_OBS_HOOK` layer, so this issue (likely) does not concern me at this point.

The final 3 errors are what bother me.  Does the "`Requested layer "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation" was wrong bit-type!`" indicate that I have a 32/64-bit mismatch between this particular validation layer and my build system, or something else?  If this is the error, I am not quite sure how to resolve the issue.  The instance and debug messenger error codes translate to `VK_ERROR_LAYER_NOT_PRESENT` and `VK_ERROR_EXTENSION_NOT_PRESENT` respectively.  The layer-in-question is the validation layer I am having problems with, and the extension-in-question is `VK_EXT_debug_utils`, which depends on the validation layers to work.

## What I Have Tried:

- Check the Vulkan Maintenance Tool for potential repairs (nothing).
- Check the Vulkan Configurator & all system environment variables (all paths correct).
- Reinstall the Vulkan SDK; this appeared to do nothing.
- Reinstall MinGW because I am out of ideas.

## What I Need to Solve the Problem:

- What does this error mean?  I cannot find documentation online; maybe I haven't looked hard enough.
- What are some potential solutions I haven't tried already?

## Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution:

My version of MinGW was the 32-bit version.  I installed MinGW-64, and specified `-m64` in GCC's options when making the project.  This also revealed a few validation performance warnings that I was not getting on System 1.  I also discovered a few misplaced calls to `free()` which were not causing any issues in my 32-bit build.  Strange, but I'm glad I got that all worked out.